# Is it always possible to increase the set of LI columns of a matrix if the rank is higher?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a $m \times n$ real matrix. Let $K$ be the rank of the matrix.

Let $C = \{ C_1, \dots, C_n \}$ be the set of columns of the matrix.

Let S be an arbitrary subset of $C$ in which all columns are linearly independent and $|S| \lt K$.

Is it guaranteed that I can find another column $C_x$, not in $S$, such that the new set $S \cup \{C_x\}$ is a set of linearly independent columns?

*Note: I know that whether true or false, this is probably a know problem, but since I don't know a name for this, I couldn't search for it. Thanks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_1, \ldots, T_m$ be the other columns.  If $S \cup \{T_1\}$ is linearly independent, you have your $C_x$.  If not, then $\text{span}(S \cup \{T_1\}) = \text{span}(S)$.  Show by induction that
if none of $S \cup \{T_1\},\ldots, S \cup \{T_k\}$ are linearly independent, then
$\text{span}(S \cup \{T_1,\ldots,T_k\}) = \text{span}(S)$.  But we know $\text{span}(S \cup \{T_1,\ldots,T_m\})$ has dimension $K > 
|S|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\text{ rank}(X)=k, k\leq n, k \leq m$ you know the matrix $X$ will have exactly $k$ linearly indipendent columns. So, as long as $|S|< k$ you can always find a column in $X$ that is linearly indipendent with every column in $S$. If $|S|=k$ you cannot find another linearly indipendent column and $S$ will be a basis of $\text{im}(X)$.

Comment: You're simply stating that it is true... This is not so clear to me, since perhaps there is only one set A of K columns that are LI, but many sets of K-1 columns that are LI, possibly including a set that is not a subset of A, hence my question.,